# Perl error: use of uninitialized value $DBI::err in concatenation

Tags: perl, dbi

I wrote a procedure which imports data from an xml-file into a MariaDB using library DBI. The procedure works but I don't understand why the following code gives me the message:

```
use of uninitialized value $DBI::err in concatenation (.) or string at ...
```

Here the code (abbreviated):

```
my $insert_art = $dbh->prepare(
    "INSERT INTO odbb_articles (creation_dt,ref_data,comp_no)". 
     "VALUES (?,?,?)"
);
....
my $comp_no = $xpc->findvalue('./sr:ARTCOMP/sr:COMPNO',$node1);
....
$insert_art->execute($creation_dt,$ref_data,$comp_no)
or die "Fehler bei der Ausfuehrung: ".
       "$DBI::err -> $DBI::errstr (odbb_articles $DBI::state)\n";
```

If I insert the code

```
if ($comp_no eq "") { $comp_no = undef; }
```

just before *$insert_art->execute* the procedure works. This error happens when there is no entry in the xml-file for element COMPNO. I can avoid it if I define it as undef. I just wonder

1. why $comp_no cause this problem and
2. is there another solution than to control if $comp_no is "" and define it as undef?

The reason for the second question is to avoid the if statement if there are a lot of variables/columns which may have empty entries.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> use of uninitialized value $DBI::err in concatenation (.) or string at ...

The error message you are seeing is Perl telling you that `$DBI::err` is `undef`. That is not because of the value of your `$comp_no`. It's just a result of what your program is doing.

So when you pass an empty string to the `comp_no` column, the database doesn't like that. It throws an error. DBI catches that error and passes it on. The `$insert_art->execute` returns a false value and the right-hand-side of the `or` gets called. That's your `die`.

Now in the string that you pass to `die` you put three variables:

- `$DBI::err`
- `$DBI::errstr`
- `$DBI::state`

According to [the DBI documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI), those are equivalent to the functions `$h->err`, `$h->errstr` and `$h->state` with `$h` being the *last handle used*. Let's look at the docs for those.

- [`$h->err`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#err)

  > Returns the native database engine error code from the last driver method called. The code is typically an integer but you should not assume that.
  >
  > The DBI resets $h->err to undef before almost all DBI method calls, so the value only has a short lifespan. Also, for most drivers, the statement handles share the same error variable as the parent database handle, so calling a method on one handle may reset the error on the related handles. [...]

  This does not explain when it can be `undef`.
- [`$h->errstr`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#errstr)

  > Returns the native database engine error message from the last DBI method called. This has the same lifespan issues as the "err" method described above.
  >
  > The returned string may contain multiple messages separated by newline characters.
  >
  > The errstr() method should not be used to test for errors, use err() for that, because drivers may return 'success with information' or warning messages via errstr() for methods that have not 'failed'.

  Ok, so this is text. Don't use it to test for specific errors. You're not doing that. You just want to give debug output when the program fails.
- [`$h->state`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#state)

  > Returns a state code in the standard SQLSTATE five character format. Note that the specific success code 00000 is translated to any empty string (false). If the driver does not support SQLSTATE (and most don't), then state() will return S1000 (General Error) for all errors.
  >
  > The driver is free to return any value via state, e.g., warning codes, even if it has not declared an error by returning a true value via the "err" method described above.
  >
  > The state() method should not be used to test for errors, use err() for that, because drivers may return a 'success with information' or warning state code via state() for methods that have not 'failed'.

  Again, this is not very clear about how useful it is.

My advice is to get rid of `$DBI::err` and `$DBI::state`. You don't need those to figure out what the problem is. Just output `$DBI::errstr`.

```
$insert_art->execute($creation_dt,$ref_data,$comp_no)
  or die "Fehler bei der Ausfuehrung: " . $dbh->errstr;
```

Now your program will still fail, but at least you will have a meaningful error message that will explain what your database didn't like about the statement. That's better than being told how there is a bug in your error handling code.

Afterwards, the other answers will probably apply to fix the reason this is happening in the first case.

---

On another note, a word on [`die`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html): If you provide a `\n` at the end of your arguments, it will not print your current script, line number and input handle line number. But those might be useful in your case. You can include them.

Comment: Perfect. I have to test that as soon I'm at work. Reading the comment it remind me the warnings caused by importing into a MySQL-DB of empty values from a csv-fil which I avoid with nullif(col,'').

Answer (score 2):

In a SQL database an empty string is very different to null.
If comp_no has a foreign key pointing to a record in another table, then the value "" is an accettable one only if there is a record with "" as primary key, very improbable.

Yu can fix this converting empty values to *undef*:

```
for ($creation_dt,$ref_data,$comp_no ){
  defined $_  and $_ eq '' and  $_ =  undef;
}
$insert_art->execute($creation_dt,$ref_data,$comp_no);
```

or also

```
$insert_art->execute(map {defined($_) && length($_) ? $_ : undef} ($creation_dt,$ref_data,$comp_no));
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment and code. The attributes/columns in my case have no keys. I suppose that if I define variable with value "" as undef, DBI considers this as database NULL and there is no errors. Does the import stopps if the value is "" due to convention to force the programmer to define the variable if there is no value?

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible shortcut:

```
$comp_no ||= undef;
```

With the caveat that this will work in any case where `$comp_no` evaluates as false, meaning a value of 0 will actually cause the result to go undef also, which may or may not matter to you.  If your field is numeric, I'd say it matters a lot.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting and dangerous shortcut. I will use it in other cases. In my situation I have values with 0.

Comment: Thanks for reading the disclaimer.  It's a personal favorite...  I actually use `$var ||= 0` a lot when I want to convert all blanks or undefs to zero.